# How to check if NetStream is playing

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a flash video player, using Open Video Player.
I need to know if the OVPNetStream (which subclasses NetStream) is playing, but I can't find a property or a status eventfor that..

And I don't want to go through the hassle of having the 'play' 'pause' 'stop' buttons to update a boolean var (because other that those buttons I suspect there may be a billion reasons for the status to change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no option already on OVPNetSteram you should probably set the playing state from the "NetStream.Play.*" status events.

Comment: Yes indeed, as Theo says, you have to track the state yourself.